# Alfresco Activiti Workflow: How to show popup dialog (message box) confirm in button?

Tags: popup, alfresco, message, activiti, confirm

I define own outcome-contraint for in  workflow-model same as (File: test-model.xml):

```
                <constraints>
                    <constraint name="my:myOutcomeOptions" type="LIST">
                        <parameter name="allowedValues">
                            <list>
                                <value>Approve</value>
                                <value>Reject</value>
                            </list>
                        </parameter>
                    </constraint>
                </constraints>
```

And custom sequence-flows to workflow definition (File: test.bpmn20.xml):

```
<exclusiveGateway id="exclusiveGateway1"</exclusiveGateway>
<sequenceFlow id="flow3" name="Rejected" sourceRef="exclusiveGateway1" targetRef="Rejected">
    <conditionExpression xsi:type="tFormalExpression"> <![CDATA[${test_a1approvecount < test_a2approvecount}]]> </conditionExpression>
</sequenceFlow>
```

I want to when I click button "Reject" showing popup confirm and after click button in popup confirm (OK and Cancel) display change to dashboard.
Please help me!

Thank you advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO! So you show us your code... what did you try? Any research?

Comment: Hi DavidGarcíaBodego, I have researched through this document: https://blog.arvixe.com/pop-up-form-in-alfresco-share/ but I do not yet understand how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add this code in function "onClick".

> ```
>   var reviewTaskTransition = document.getElementsByName("prop_my_myOutcomeOptions")[0].value;
>
>   if(reviewTaskTransition == "Approve"){   
>
>        Alfresco.util.submitForm(p_obj.getForm());
>
>
>    } else if(reviewTaskTransition == "Reject"){    
>
>       Alfresco.util.PopupManager.displayPrompt({
>            title: "Rejection Popup",
>            text: "confirm?",
>            noEscape: true,
>            buttons: [{
>                text: "Yes",
>                handler: function submitRejection() {
>                   Alfresco.util.submitForm(p_obj.getForm());
>                   this.destroy();
>                }
>            },
>
>            {
>            text: "no",
>            handler: function() {
>            this.destroy();
>            document.location.reload(true);
>            },
>            isDefault: true
>            },
>
>            ]
>            });
>
>     }
>     else{
>        Alfresco.util.submitForm(p_obj.getForm()); 
>     }
> ```

Comment: Thank Gercio_J, I updated it a bit more: var buttonId = p_obj.get("id");  Next line: if(buttonId.inclues("Approve")) { something code} ...! Thank you to everyone helped me.

Comment: It's embarrassing to bother you. I don't know where to put activiti-transitions.js file in my project so that when I build AMP and deloy it will be in /components/form/workflow/activiti-transitions.js in tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

This is bit difficult to implement in alfresco.One more thing is you are confusing your self with back end and front end and you are confusing others too.

First things is , bpmn file is the backend stuff so what ever changes you make in that , it will not show pop up in front end.

For your requirement what you need to do is to make the workflow from configuration changes.Below are certain example where you can find the details of how you can customize the form.

https://hub.alfresco.com/t5/ecm-archive/task-done-transition/m-p/125211/thread-id/66680
https://docs.alfresco.com/6.1/references/dev-extension-points-workflow.html

You can google as well ;)

Comment: Refer : https://github.com/fufler/dynamic-activiti-transitions

Comment: I create 2 new file: "/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/workflow/activiti-transitions.ftl"(template popup)  and  "/components/form/workflow/activiti-transitions.js" (function process) and add a new contain in "share-config-custom.xml" . But I don't know how to create a "activiti-transitions.ftl" file content to display a "Are you sure?" in message box and have "OK" and "Cancle" buttons.
Please guide me.

Comment: You do not need to make changes in ftl file.Ftl is similar to html file.It is javascript which can render popup.In side javascript file there will be function to submit the workflow form.In that function you can check it if it has been rejected you can shoe the popup.for displaying popup you can use popup manager of alfresco.

Comment: Hi  Krutik Jayswal, I custom function "onClick" in a file "activiti-transitions.js". I use Alfresco.util.PopupManager but when I add it doesn't see the change on Alfresco .  I re-run Alfresco when I saw the "activiti-transitions.js" file was created. The "activiti-transitions.js" file I found here: MyDesktop \ alfresco \ workflow-tutorial \ target \ tomcat \ webapps \ workflow-tutorial-share \ components \ form \ workflow  .    Did I do something wrong?